# Can we use a value for defaultValue in react-select that is passed from another component as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The passed prop has same values as the one in the options array. The reason why I am doing it this way is because I am using a modal to edit a row. The data is passed from row to modal. Modal has the options but I want the data to be pre-populated. There seems no way that I can populate the react-select dropdown.
`options = [
{ id: 0, value: 'New', label: 'New' },
{ id: 1, value: 'In Progress', label: 'In Progress' },
{ id: 2, value: 'Blocked', label: 'Blocked' },
{ id: 3, value: 'Complete', label: 'Complete' }
];

```
getSelectedStatus = (status) => {
    this.options.map((selected) => {
        if (selected.value === status) {
            this.setState({
                selectedOption: selected.id
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(this.state.selectedOption);
};`
```

I used a function like this to get the selectedOption id and then at least that way pass to the defaultValue property inside render(), but it is not working. Any help please?

Comment: Where did u call this function?

Comment: I called it in componentDidMount() so that as soon as I get this.props.status I can assigned an option to selectedOption

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the selected option on every onChange event.
If you use it as in the example I shared below, you can use this component by calling all its fields and sending the data in options.

```
 static defaultProps = {
    options: [],
    components: undefined,
  };

handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    onChange(selectedOption.value);
  };



 render() {
    const {
      value, name, options, components} = this.props;
    return (
      <Select
        name={name}
        value={(value === '') ? null : options.find(obj => obj.value === 
        value)}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
        className="react-select"
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        
      />
    );
  }




  return (
    <>
      <SelectField
        {...input}
        options={options}
        components={components}
      />
   
  );
};

renderSelectField.defaultProps = {
  options: [],
  components: undefined,
};
```

You can send the data in the field you want to use as follows.

```
  options={data && data.map((values) => { return ({value: values?.id, label: values?.label}); })}
```